# Vbulletin on nginx?

Tags: nginx, vbulletin

As an nginx fan, I need to set up a VB for a friend so I am wondering whether one can server VB site using nginx/php-fpm instead of apache? What are the specefic rewrite rules for that? How common this approach is and whether there are any benefits in doing so?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can run vBulletin with nginx.

The rewrite rules you need will be specific to your setup and any modules you are using (you do not need any rewrite rules to run a standard vBulletin installation unless you use [SEO Friendly URLs](https://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/main/options_seofriendly_urls) - see this [vBulletin forum post](https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/showthread.php/400793-Nginx-Rewrite-Rules-for-SEO-Mod-Rewrite-Friendly-URLs)).

Many popular mods have already had their rules translated, (e.g. [vbSEO](http://www.vbseo.com/f4/howto-nginx-23485/)) however, you can refer to the [nginx HttpRewriteModule documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule) to add your own as needed.